# CComSafeArray to Tab-Separated Values Suggestions for Speed Improvement

Tags: c++, visual-c++, com

I have the need to convert a 2D CComSafe Array into a tab-separated values text stream. The array can contain an arbitrary number of values, potentially in the millions.

The relevant chunks of code is below.

I strongly suspect that the generate_response_from_data function is just an atrocious way to generate the output. But I have not found a concrete example of a better way. And yes, I have searched to the best of my ability.

I tried to figure out whether Boost Karma would be a better solution, but frankly, I just couldn't figure out how to apply it to my use case.

Can someone provide some input as to a faster method?

```
// This is a 2D CComSafeArray
template<typename T>
class MyDataArray : public CComSafeArray<T>
{
public:
    MyDataArray() : CComSafeArray<T>() {}

    const T* get_value_ptr(long row, long col) const // 0-based indices.
    {
        // To shave off a tiny bit of time, validity of m_psa, row, and col are assumed.
        // Not great but for our application, those are checked prior to call.
        return &static_cast<T*>(this->m_psa->pvData)[this->m_psa->rgsabound[1].cElements * col + row];
    }

    // Other stuff for this class.
};

inline std::string my_variant_to_string(const VARIANT* p_var)
{
    // Will only ever have VT_I4, VT_R8, VT_BSTR
    if (VT_I4 == p_var->vt)
        return boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(p_var->intVal); // Boost faster than other methods!!!

    if (VT_R8 == p_var->vt)
        return boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(p_var->dblVal); // Boost faster than other methods!!!

    if (VT_BSTR == p_var->vt)
    {
        std::wstring wstr(p_var->bstrVal, SysStringLen(p_var->bstrVal));
        return Utils::from_wide(wstr); // from_wide is a conversion function I created.
    }

    //if (VT_EMPTY == == p_var->vt) {} // Technically not needed.

    return "";
}

template<typename T>
bool generate_response_from_data(const MyDataArray<T>& data_array, std::stringstream& response_body)
{
    if (2 != data_array.GetDimensions())
        return false;

    long row_begin = data_array.GetLowerBound(0);
    long row_end = data_array.GetUpperBound(0);
    long col_begin = data_array.GetLowerBound(1);
    long col_end = data_array.GetUpperBound(1);

    if (row_end < row_begin || col_end < col_begin)
        return false;

    for (long r = row_begin; r <= row_end; ++r)
    {
        for (long c = col_begin; c <= col_end; ++c)
        {
            if (c > 0)
                response_body << '\t';

            response_body << my_variant_to_string(data_array.get_value_ptr(r, c));
        }
        response_body << '\n';
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: The fine-grained locking that used in iostreams to make it thread-safe tends to be noticeable.  But the "response_body" variable name strongly hints that there is nothing you can do in your code to make it any faster.   Verify this by replacing my_variant_to_string() with "testing".

Comment: Try to make an assumption about the size of the resulting string, And reserve space before you fill it,

Comment: You're creating a lot of temporary strings. Try changing your `my_variant_to_string` into a `<<` operator overload for `VARIANT&` instances, and write directly to the stream from `intVal` / `dblVal`. Can you use wide strings in your case? If so, you could stream directly from `bstrVal` as well.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestions everyone. I will investigate them (especially overloading <<) but it may take a few days to get to it. I will report back as soon as I have results.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelGunter. your suggestion to overload << results in a ~60% increase in speed! Next to investigate allocating size for stringstream (e.g. in 1 MB chunks) and allocating more as need for bigger size (e.g. in additional 1 MB chunks). Then truncating final result as needed. If anyone has a suggested implementation, it might be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @MichaelGunter. Your suggestion to overload << results in a ~60% increase in speed! I convert from wstring for each value because the percentage of string values is fairly small (if any at all) compared to the numeric values and converting the entire stream may be a waste in most cases.

EDITED to reflect direct conversion from BSTR to std::string using custom function.

```
std::stringstream& operator<<(std::stringstream& s, const VARIANT* p_v)
{
    if (VT_I4 == p_v->vt)
        s << p_v->intVal;
    else if (VT_R8 == p_v->vt)
        s << p_v->dblVal;
    else if (VT_BSTR == p_v->vt)
    {
        //std::wstring wstr(p_v->bstrVal, SysStringLen(p_v->bstrVal));
        s << Utils::from_bstr(p_v->bstrVal);
    }
    return s;
}

...
response_body << odata_array.get_value_ptr(r, c);
```

Comment: You should also have a `Utils::from_wide` overload that takes a `BSTR` and yields an `std::string` without the temporary `std::wstring`. Super easy to do if you're just using `WideCharToMultiByte`.

Comment: @Michael Guner. Thanks for the additional hint. It further increased speed.

Comment: I suspect I'd get even more increased speed by optimizing stringstream and perhaps pre-allocating as suggested by @xMRi and others. But I am unsure of optimizations and cannot find info about pre-allocating space and/or increasing allocated space.